# how to merge two cells in microsoft report builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I want am working on a Microsoft Report Builder project, but it doesn't allow me to merge the cells in the third part.

When I right click in the third part, there is no option to merge.

Any ideas please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and show the actual report design. I would guess it's because you are trying to merge across different scopes (e.g. a detail row and a total row or a row outside the group) but it's difficult to tell without seeing the design

Comment: @AlanSchofield check the question again please, I have updated a photo about what I mean.

Comment: You need to show the report design, including any row and column groups, take screen shot of the report in design mode

Comment: The only way to get the format that you want is to have a sub report for column 3 with the multiple rows.